# Installation error: Unknown failure 5

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

My application worked very well till today, but now when I try to run app, it gives me this error:

```
[2015-05-04 22:21:44 - probajedan] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2015-05-04 22:21:44 - probajedan] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2015-05-04 22:21:44 - probajedan] Launch canceled!
```

I tried everything I found on internet but nothing helps.

It's master/detail flow application

SS of logcat is in comment.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/71k55z

Comment: http://prntscr.com/71k5bv

Comment: Which part of this is supposed to be useful?

Comment: Please include *something* more than you have.  Perhaps copy and paste the LogCat since you can't include images?  As-is, this question is useless.